# Is there a URL or site like example.org which always produces a 404 error?

Tags: http, testing

The [example.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) domain is for documentation purposes and a http request always resolves to it, so you get a [HTTP 200 (OK) status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_200) which means it can be used for positive testing.

Is there a URL for which it is known to always [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) that can be used for negative testing?

Answer (score 3):

[Studio 404si](http://www.studio404.net) has [posted links to a few pages](https://plus.google.com/+Studio404si) of which the Google 404 actually gives a 404 http status code:

- http://www.google.com/404

I found another page on Google that generates a status code, so I suspect there are more.

This one returns [HTTP 204 (No Content) status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_204):

- http://www.google.com/generate_204

And of course the main site returns HTTP 200 (OK):

- http://www.google.com

There is also [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/) which can return any kind of result code over http, https and servers in the EU and USA. It can even return [http status code 418](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#418):

- http://httpbin.org/status/418